# Wolfram Tech Conference 2016

Tags: discussion

[image: WTC 2016]

Are there many SE members going to WTC this year? Should we schedule a meeting, coffee or a dedicated table for dinner?

Comment: I'll be there again this year.

Comment: I'll be there this year.

Comment: I'll be there, it's my first time WTC.

Comment: @Kuba I work remotely. I don't have a clue who to ask.

Comment: @xslittlegrass, we should try to meet up when you are there.

Comment: @Kuba, getting such a table should be fairly straight forward. Just ask the people at the WRI reception and I am sure they will gladly help out.

Comment: @user21 thanks I will :)

Comment: same here, first WTC

Comment: I will be there. This is my first WTC (I'm also giving a talk)!

Comment: Stickers?! (Also I'm local so I will be there.)

Comment: @xslittlegrass I look forward to meeting you.

Comment: "I ordered ~25 stickers from Stackexchange Team. Is that enough?" -- Hard to tell: how many stickers per person are envisioned / allowed?

Comment: I'm here. Anyone else here yet.  Lunch tomorrow before the Keynote?

Comment: @kuba Okay. 3:30 in the lobby.

Comment: @Lame-Ov2.0 When is your talk?

Comment: @Edmund it is Friday at 9:30am!

Comment: @Kuba stuffed in a cube doing some work. :) Want to meet up this morning?

Comment: @Kuba There's a talk at 9, in Badger, that I'd like to see. I'll meet you outside it afterwards?

Comment: Another great conference this year.  It was good to catch up with everyone and see some new faces.  I look forward to seeing you all next year.

Comment: @Edmund and Pfonseca, share some photos :)

Comment: LOL - I didn't take any.  @Pfonseca has a few. I need to update my phone.

Comment: Oh crap! How didn't I notice this thread?! I was at the WTC and had a talk on liquid film dynamics.

Comment: @drN, oh, you are drN... I went to see your talk. It was quite good, quite impressive! NDSolve rocks ;-)

Comment: @user21 Yes. NDSolve changed my life... a bit `;)` .  I am glad you liked my talk.  It was a great opportunity to not just practice my talk but also do a "live dynamic presentation" unlike "Static presentations" at most scientific conferences.